# Symfony2 form of checkboxes is not updated when nothing is checked

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I have user entity and activity. User has many activities. I've created a form -> list of users and theris activitis (checkboxes).

```
User, ACT1, ACT2, ACT3

Jhon---x--------0--------0
```

x- checkbox is checked

0- checkbox is unchecked

Everythings works fine when I have data like above and press save button, but when I want to uncheck all activities:

```
User, ACT1, ACT2, ACT3

Jhon---0--------0--------0
```

(I press save button) The activietes are not updated. $_POST Is empty and I think there is no bindig in controller.
Single checkbox is generated by form_widget in this way:

```
input type="checkbox" name="users_activities[users][0][activities][1][enabled]" value="1" checked="checked"
```

Any idea how to solve it?

VIEW:

```
{%for actv in user.activities %}
    {{ form_widget(actv.enabled) }}
{%endfor%}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());
    foreach ($form->get('users') as $userF) {
        foreach ($userF->get('activities') as $actF) {
            $act = $actF->getData();
            $em->persist($act);
        }
    }
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: Can you post the php code that renders your form and your controller (or at least the action)?

Comment: You should check if `$form->get('users')` is null before you iterate through it.